Distances between specific hyperplanes as nonlinear optimization problem
For any sets $X, Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, the distance between them is defined as $$d(X,Y) = \operatorname{min}_{\mathbf{x} \in X, \mathbf{y} \in Y} = \sqrt{(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})^{T}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})}$$ Consider the hyperplanes
\begin{align*}
  X &= \left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x} = c - 1 \right\}\\
  Y &= \left\{\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{y} = c + 1 \right\}
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{b} = 1$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to prove that:
\begin{equation*}
  d(X,Y) =
  \begin{cases}
    2 & \text{if } \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}\\
    2|c| & \text{if } \mathbf{a} = -\mathbf{b}\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
I have set this up as the nonlinear optimization problem
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rl}
    \operatorname{min} & f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})^{T}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})\\
    \text{subject to } & g_{1}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x} - c + 1 = 0\\
    & g_{2}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{y} - c - 1 = 0
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}
The Lagrangian is then $$L(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{\lambda} = (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})^{T}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}) + \lambda_{1} \left(\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x} - c + 1\right) + \lambda_{2} \left(\mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{y} - c - 1\right)$$ and the gradient of the Lagrangian is then
\begin{equation*}
  \nabla L(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{\lambda}) =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2x_{1} - 2y_{1}\\
    2x_{2} - 2y_{2}\\
    \vdots\\
    2x_{n} - 2y_{n}\\
    2y_{1} - 2x_{1}\\
    \vdots\\
    2y_{n} - 2x_{n}\\
    0\\
    0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  + \lambda_{1}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{1}\\
    a_{2}\\
    \vdots\\
    a_{n}\\
    0\\
    \vdots\\
    0\\
    \mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x} - c + 1\\
    0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \lambda_{2}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    \vdots\\
    0\\
    b_{1}\\
    \vdots\\
    b_{n}\\
    0\\
    \mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{y} - c - 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Setting this to zero we have
\begin{align*}
  2x_{i} - 2y_{i} + \lambda_{1}a_{i} &= 0\\
  2y_{i} - 2x_{i} + \lambda_{2}b_{i} &= 0\\
  \mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x} - c + 1 &= 0\\
  \mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{y} - c - 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
Adding the second system of equations to the first cancels all the $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$, leaving
\begin{align*}
  \lambda_{1} \mathbf{a} + \lambda_{2} \mathbf{b} &= 0\\
  \mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x} - c + 1 &= 0\\
  \mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{y} - c - 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
I am not sure how I can use this information to prove the required results. Any suggestions?

So you would only compute the gradient with respect to $x$ and $y$. Not familiar with what you're doing by taking the gradient with respect to $\lambda$ as well. So we have:
\begin{align}
\nabla_{x,y}L&=(2x-2y,2y-2x)+\lambda_1(a,0) + \lambda_2 (0,b) = 0\\
x\cdot a &= c-1 \\
y\cdot b &= c+1
\end{align}
In the case where $a=b$, we have:
\begin{align}
(a,a)\cdot\nabla_{x,y}L&=0+\lambda_1 \|a\|^2 + \lambda_2 \|a\|^2 = 0\\
&\lambda_1+ \lambda_2 = 0\\
(a,-a)\cdot\nabla_{x,y}L&=4(x-y)\cdot a+\lambda_1 \|a\|^2 - \lambda_2 \|a\|^2 = 0\\
&=-8+\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 = 0\\
\implies& \lambda_1=4, \lambda_2=-4\\
\implies& 2x-2y + 4a=0\\
\implies& x-y=-2a\\
\implies& \|x-y\|=2
\end{align}
Follow the same method to prove the results for $a=-b$.
For the third case, the planes intersect. We can see by considering the 2D subspace $\text{span}(a,b)$. When intersected with this space, the hyperplanes become lines with different normal vectors, which obviously intersect. Hence the original hyperplanes intersect and the minimum distance is 0.
